# How to check many conditions in custom column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

[image]

Can anyone help me that how can I check many conditions and one result in the custom column?

example : `If [state code ] = [CT ,MA,PA,ME,MT,VT][1]` I want the result as `North East`.

How to check the condition in the custom column?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, Seems like reserved words like if, then, else are case sensitive in power query.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help but the result only shows "other region" however the matched data are not come out :( I m not sure what's wrong

Comment: Can you also post the screenshot of Custom Column that you have created?

Comment: I have added it. Thanks

Comment: Please double check your state codes that you have entered in the custom column name, Probably that is where the problem is...Also I noticed that there is no "MD" as state code..i guess it should be "MT"..Please recheck all

Comment: ok I have tried with fewer data set only 2 State codes "NY" & "NJ" but still same as return data as "others".

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom column code as follows:

```
If ( [state code ] IN {"CT" ,"MA","PA","ME","MT","VT"},"North East", "other" )
```